# javascript: Select a class with the right content

Tags: javascript

i`m working on a Greasmonkey Script, no i want to know how i can test a class for its content.
For example:

```
<div class="same">Some content</div>
<div class="same">Other content</div>
<div class="same">evenmorecontent</div>
<div class="same">yesthisisalsocontent</div>
<div class="same">youmaynotizedthat</div>
<div class="same">thecontentisdifferent</div>
<div class="same">the cake is yellow</div>
```

Now i create a array with this classes

```
var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('same');
```

Now i want to get the position of "evenmorecontent" in the Array! How do i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to use jQuery, you could do this in one line with the [contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector.

In straght JS you need to loop through the array:

```
var pos = -1;
for(var x=0;x<arr.length;arr++) {
     if(arr[x].innerHTML.indexOf('evenmorecontent')>-1) {
         pos = x;
    }
}
```

If it occurs more than once, this will return the last position. It will return -1 if not found.

Comment: very clean and simple answer!

Comment: Ninja edit. And with that I realized it was innerHTML, not value :)

Answer (score 1):

Try not to mix vanilla JS and jQuery while doing this. The following function returns the position of the first occurrence of the text:

```
var getTextPosition = function (selector, text) {
  var pos = -1;
  $(selector).each(function(index) { 
    if($(this).text() === text) {
      pos = index;
      return false;    
    }
  }); 
  return pos;
};
```

Example usage:

```
getTextPosition(".same", "evenmorecontent");
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with just one selector. You'll have to loop:

```
var sameEl = (function() {
  var sameArr = document.getElementsByClassName('same');
  for (index in sameArr) {
    if (sameArr[index].innerHTML === 'evenmorecontent') {
      return sameArr[index];
    }
  }
})();
```